# ARIA Alternative to Labels that use the Form Element's Very Very Long ID

Tags: html, forms, wai-aria

I'm adding various Accessibility standards to our enterprise platform UI framework. We use a web client, DOM elements, etc. We render all of the framework in the DOM, but widgets in the framework can (and have for years) been put together in non standard ways by customers to build out various pages of their UI.

I've managed to cover and handle much of the specifications (I think), but I have a specific case, where we have "texty labely widgets" that are used to describe various "input / formlike widgets". Their only connection as far as the DOM goes is a common parent "container" element, a variable distance up the tree.

The ARIA guidelines I'm coming across (which at any point I may have misunderstood) suggest I need to use `aria-labeledby="id_of_text_label_widget"` on the actual form element. Meaning what I have now is:

```
<div id="parent_label_value_widget_001">
  <div class="inputLabel">This is visible Label Text</div>
  <div class="various_other_junk_in_here"></div>
  <div class="some_wrapper_around_the_input">
    <input id="I_am_the_form_input_in_question_with_a_very_long_id" value="42">
  </div>
</div>
```

I could easily add the `aria-labeledby` attr to the input, but it means I'd need to add an id to the `inputLabel` element. And while this seems like not a big deal (it's slightly more complicated because what you see in the DOM is the result of a far more complicated render cycle from a WYSIWYG editor of disconnected widgets), it happens to be, with no possibility for change, that our ids are incredibly long already. Due to huge pages, sometimes tens of thousands of fields and nested dynamic things, etc

Our Ids make up 60% of our payload. And I'd effectively have to double that chunk by adding a new id to every label element, and our content isn't gzipped. So that's what I'm trying to avoid. I actually also don't want to do it for other reasons, as the label widget and the input widget actually know nothing about one another, so I'd have to write some extra render logic to have the input widget pull the id from the sibling label widget.

**My question is: does anybody have any other solutions?**

Things I've imagined:
A. Is there some technique using aria-label, where I could label the parent container and have screen readers know how to link the internal label and input?

B. I could duplicate the label text from the label widget onto the input widget and use `aria-label="duplicated text"`. I could do this server side with some pain, or client side with some clumsy walking logic, but would rather avoid the duplication, and the extra logic. But if I do that, then do I need to aria-hide all the existing label widgets?

C. Is there some shorthand for `<label for="">` or `aria-labeledby=""` where instead of an id, it can reference elements by css selector, or proximity? (Dreaming, I know), but it's a shot.

D. Make the user opt in to aria support, and only then do they get the doubled package size. (yeah, I know gzip would solve alot of this, but it's a long story why it's not in place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `<input>` elements need some kind of label and that label has to be directly associated with, or "tied to", the `<input>`.  "Proximity" is not a direct association.  That is, just because a label is "close" to the input in the DOM, that doesn't tie the two elements together.

Some screen readers will try to look for some text to use as a label if one is not explicitely found, but that usually involves going to the previous sibling of the `<input>` in the DOM and if that sibling has some kind of text associated with it, then treat that like the label.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  I would not rely on it.

For example,

```
<label>password</label>
<p>should contain upper and lower case letters, a number, and a special character</p>
<input>
```

In this case, the "should contain..." text will be treated as the input's label, which is wrong.  It doesn't matter that there is a `<label>` element prior to the `<p>`.  There is nothing in the DOM tying the `<label>` to the `<input>`.  The above example should be written as:

```
<label for="pw">password</label>
<p id="rules">should contain upper and lower case letters, a number, and a special character</p>
<input id="pw" aria-describedby="rules">
```

This associates **both** text elements with the input.  The `<label>` is tied directly via the `for` attribute (and the ID on the `<input>`) and the description of the password is tied via the `aria-describedby` on the `<input>`.

So the first choice of labelling an input should be with native html, if possible.  Use the `for` attribute of the `<label>`.

Another way to label, as you noted, is using the `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` on the `<input>` itself.  While this will give the input an [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name) for screen readers, it won't help sighted users.  The `aria-label` is not a visible thing.  However, in your case, it looks like there is already a visual label (even if it's not officially "tied" to the input).

So, to comment on your four proposals (A-D):

A. You can put `aria-label` on the parent container but the `<input>` would still need to be told to look at the parent to retrieve the label, and that's done with `aria-labelledby` on the `<input>` (and would require an ID on the parent so you can point to it.).

B. If you put the `aria-label` directly on the `<input>`, then yes, you should set `aria-hidden="true"` on the visible label, otherwise a screen reader user can navigate to the visible label text and then navigate to the input and hear the same text again.  But that's an odd solution.  If the text is already visible, the best thing is to put an ID on the visible text and associate it with the `<input>` via `aria-labelledby`.

C. Worth a short, but no.

D. This is a friendly place so all ideas will be considered, but please do not do this.  Do not segregate different types of users or force people to opt-in to an accessible site.

It sounds like your main argument for not creating an accessible solution is the size of your page.  Not to be dramatic, but that wouldn't hold up in court.  That is, if your site ended up being the defendant in litigation, arguing that you didn't implement accessibility because you didn't want the page load to be larger would not be a valid reason.  That's just an implementation problem on your end.

Comment: Yeah. I'm gonna get the framework to be ARIA / ADA friendly. I was just hoping for a solution that didn't bloat the payload, while still working in the ancient constraints we have. It sounds like the `aria-labeledby` pointing to the associated label is the recommendation, but man, that means adding an id to the label, and then copying that id into the labeledby. Will be a 2.5x increase in payload size. Blech.

Comment: The first recommendation is to use `<label for="id">` / `<input id="id">`.  If that can't be done, the next recommendation is to use `aria-labelledby`.  Thanks for making your app accessible.